# How to show a:focus color and outline in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

It seems that usually people want to get rid of the browser focus outline and that is why I can't find the answer to this question.

I am trying to show an outline and also change the color of anchor tags after they have been clicked. The following code works as expected on Chrome and Firefox **but not on Safari** (on Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25.1) for example I only see the color changing when you click, but returns to the original color afterwards).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

a:focus {
  color:red;
  outline-style: dotted;
  outline-color: red;
  outline-width: 2px;
}

</style>

</head> 
<body>

<a href='#'>Click Me</a>
<a href='#'>Click Me Also</a>

</body>
</html>
```

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adsfq5af/1/) (jsfiddle).

Comment: Why not use a [border](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/adsfq5af/2/)?

Comment: @jbutler483 Hmm maybe I should, but what about the color? And by the way, your fiddle also does not work on Safari (as in, you can't see the border) :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is happening because safari can render only active not focus. So we can add same css with active but behaviors of active and focus are different. Focus remains the ouline till other click on document so we will do using add class .focusedA when click on link with added css of active. But when we click on document expect than link then remove the class, implementation of second condition is remaining i. e. removing class focusedA. I think you will do this.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("a.withAct").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("focusedA");
   $(this).off();
  });
  
  
 });
```

```css
a.withoutAct:focus,a.withAct:active,.focusedA {
  color:red;
  outline-style: dotted;
  outline-color: red;
  outline-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class="withoutAct">Click Me</a>
<a href='#' class="withAct">Click Me Also</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using -webkit- as the prefix 
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/9139/) 
For eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

a:focus {
  color:red;
  -webkit-border: 2px dotted red;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}

</style>

</head> 
<body>

<a href='#'>Click Me</a>
<a href='#'>Click Me Also</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still no luck... I think the property is called `-webkit-focus-ring-color` but I have tried it and it does not work, or at least I am not using it properly...darn browser!

Comment: Umm Try this one, http://jsfiddle.net/fpqp1zv3/13/
And make sure that your browser is up to date